# Angular 2 RC 2 Using Mobile Gestures (Swipe, Pinch, Rotate)

Tags: angular, hammer.js, angular2-template, angular2-directives, angular2-services

Can anyone please guide how to use mobile gestures in Angular 2 RC2.

May be something like:

```
<div (swipeLeft)="OnSwipeLeft()"></div>
```

From the API can see

```
HAMMER_GESTURE_CONFIG 
HammerGestureConfig
```

under

```
@angular/platform-browser
```

But not sure how to use it.

In some posts in I see some users are suggesting to include Hammer.js. But I believe if its already in api we should be able to include and use it in an easy way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok I found the solution and it works with Angular 2 RC 2:

Add hammerjs to the packages.json file

"hammerjs": "2.0.8",

Include hammerjs

```
<script src="/node_modules/hammerjs/hammer.min.js"></script>
```

Then in template:

```
<div (swipeleft)="onSwipeleft($event)" (swiperight)="onSwiperight($event)">
```

or may be something like this in template:

```
<div (swipe)="onSwipe($event)">Swipe (direction = {{swipeDirection}})</div>
<div (pinch)="onPinch($event)">pinch (scale = {{pinchScale}})</div>
<div (rotate)="onRotate($event)">Rotate (angle = {{rotateAngle}})</div>
```

and in your component:

```
class GesturesCmp {

    swipeDirection: string = '-';
    pinchScale: number = 1;
    rotateAngle: number = 0;

    onSwipe(event: any): void {
        this.swipeDirection = event.deltaX > 0 ? 'right' : 'left';
    }

    onPinch(event: any): void {
        this.pinchScale = event.scale;
    }

    onRotate(event: any): void {
        this.rotateAngle = event.rotation;
    }
}
```

Comment: Some events like pinch are disabled by default in angular2. How did you configure hammerjs to get around this?

Comment: Noremac, really sorry for the late reply. This might help https://scotch.io/tutorials/using-hammerjs-touch-gesture-in-angular-2